# Secure PHP image uploader? Where is an accepted solid solution?

Tags: php, security, upload, photo

Relative newb here. I'm not a great programmer my self, but am not too bad in finding the chunks of code, from those far cleverer than me are generous enough to share.

However, in all my hunting around, I'm yet to find a secure PHP image uploader which seems to be accepted by the web community as doing a fairly solid job.

I was wondering what people thought of this https://github.com/dimo414/imgupload

Otherwise, through all the security issues and discussions, does anybody know about any resource which I can take and adapt for the purposes of uploading a single image?

Answer (score 1):

That will work fine, but remember that this is *nothing special*, it's just **standard PHP functionality** to create it.

You could use this to get the job done quickly, but if you are using it in a specific solution then you might want to tweak it for your own needs.

This could be to make it work via ajax or something else perhaps?

Comment: +1, agreed. The code just helps refine what PHP already does.

Comment: I'm not too concerned about the beauty of it, and I don't mind tweaking it a little. My main concern is security since I intend to use it on a site which will be handling payments also, i.e. vulnerability to hacking/data theft is to be avoided at all costs.

Thanks for your quick responses BTW.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly a question suited for StackOverflow since it is less about the code you've tried and more about a subjective question of security. The code you've pointed to is good as long as you understand what it secures you from and what it doesn't. It enforces a max upload size and checks that the upload is the right type, but keep in mind that PHP is already doing some of this. The code in question just packages it up in a way that is easier to use.

This code will stop someone from uploading anything other than images and that's probably the most important part.